# Repaint Isn't doing anything

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jpanel, repaint

I am trying to make a rectangle change color with GUI sliders. I know this can be done by changing the background but I'm trying to use repaint.

I know that repaint holds the requests and executes at will almost. I'm trying to find a workaround because I'm stuck.

I've read up on repaint(); and repaintManager and tried manipulating my code but I'm still unable to get my desired output.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;

/**
 *
 *
 */
public class MyColorChooser2 extends JPanel {

    private JFrame frame;
    private JLabel redLabel, greenLabel, blueLabel;
    private JSlider redSlider, greenSlider, blueSlider;
    private JTextField redTextField, greenTextField, blueTextField;

    private JPanel redPanel, greenPanel, bluePanel, colorPanel, paintPanel;

    private int holdNbr1, holdNbr2, holdNbr3;
    DrawPanel rect = new DrawPanel();

    public MyColorChooser2() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();

        frame.setTitle("Color Chooser");

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        // set up labels
        redLabel = new JLabel("Red:");
        greenLabel = new JLabel("Green:");
        blueLabel = new JLabel("Blue:");

        // set up sliders and register their event handler:
        redSlider = new JSlider(SwingConstants.HORIZONTAL, 0, 255, 50);
        redSlider.setMajorTickSpacing(10); // create tick every 10
        redSlider.setPaintTicks(true); // paint ticks on slider

        greenSlider = new JSlider(SwingConstants.HORIZONTAL, 0, 255, 100);
        greenSlider.setMajorTickSpacing(10); // create tick every 10
        greenSlider.setPaintTicks(true); // paint ticks on slider

        blueSlider = new JSlider(SwingConstants.HORIZONTAL, 0, 255, 200);
        blueSlider.setMajorTickSpacing(10); // create tick every 10
        blueSlider.setPaintTicks(true); // paint ticks on slider

        //slider event handling:
        SliderHandler sliderHandler = new SliderHandler();
        redSlider.addChangeListener(sliderHandler);
        greenSlider.addChangeListener(sliderHandler);
        blueSlider.addChangeListener(sliderHandler);

        //set up textFields and register their event handler:
        redTextField = new JTextField(3);
        redTextField.setText("50"); //initialize
        redTextField.setEditable(false);
        redTextField.setText("" + redSlider.getValue());

        greenTextField = new JTextField(3);
        greenTextField.setText("100"); //initialize
        greenTextField.setEditable(false);
        greenTextField.setText("" + greenSlider.getValue());

        blueTextField = new JTextField(3);
        blueTextField.setText("200"); //initialize
        blueTextField.setEditable(false);
        blueTextField.setText("" + blueSlider.getValue());


        // build colorPanel:
        // build redPanel:    
        redPanel = new JPanel();
        redPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
        redPanel.add(redLabel);
        redPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));
        redPanel.add(redSlider);
        redPanel.add(redTextField);
        // build greenPanel:
        greenPanel = new JPanel();
        greenPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
        greenPanel.add(greenLabel);
        greenPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));
        greenPanel.add(greenSlider);
        greenPanel.add(greenTextField);
        // build bluePanel:
        bluePanel = new JPanel();
        bluePanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
        bluePanel.add(blueLabel);
        bluePanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));
        bluePanel.add(blueSlider);
        bluePanel.add(blueTextField);

        colorPanel = new JPanel();
        colorPanel.add(redPanel);
        colorPanel.add(greenPanel);
        colorPanel.add(bluePanel);

        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        frame.add(rect, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.add(colorPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(900, 300));
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.pack();

    }

    public class DrawPanel extends JPanel {

        private Color color;
        private int red = 50, blue = 100, green = 200;
        private Graphics g;

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            changeColor();
            g.setColor(color);

            g.fillRect(10, 10, 880, 200);
            g.dispose();

        }

        public void DrawPanel(Color c) {

            color = c;

            red = color.getRed();
            green = color.getGreen();
            blue = color.getBlue();

        }

        void changeColor() {

            color = new Color(red, green, blue);
            this.color = color;

        }

        public void setRed(int r) {
            red = r;
            changeColor();

        }

        public void setBlue(int b) {
            blue = b;
            changeColor();

        }

        public void setGreen(int g) {
            green = g;
            changeColor();

        }
    }

    private class SliderHandler implements ChangeListener {

        @Override
        public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
            JSlider change = (JSlider) e.getSource();
            DrawPanel draw = new DrawPanel();
            int value;

            if (change == redSlider) {
                value = change.getValue();
                redTextField.setText(String.valueOf(value));
                draw.setRed(value);
            } else if (change == greenSlider) {
                value = change.getValue();
                greenTextField.setText(String.valueOf(value));
                draw.setGreen(value);
            } else if (change == blueSlider) {
                value = change.getValue();
                blueTextField.setText(String.valueOf(value));
                draw.setBlue(value);
            }

            draw.changeColor();
            draw.repaint();
        }

    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        MyColorChooser2 color = new MyColorChooser2();
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you `dispose`ing your `Graphics` context there?  Surely it's not done with it yet by the time you do that!

Comment: It was one of those many things I tried to reach my end goal. I figured if I dispose of the original it would allow me to repaint a new graphic without taking as long. With and without it doesn't run as desired.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not that it isn't doing anything. The problem is that you're stuck, because every time you make a change you're trying to update a different component. You're recreating multiple panels in your state changed.

I've added comments about the changes I've done to make it work properly. If you need more help, just ask. Cheers!

Would you care trying this code:

```
public class MyColorChooser2 extends JPanel {

    private JFrame frame;
    private DrawPanel drawPanel;

    private JLabel redLabel, greenLabel, blueLabel;
    private JSlider redSlider, greenSlider, blueSlider;
    private JTextField redTextField, greenTextField, blueTextField;

    private JPanel redPanel, greenPanel, bluePanel, colorPanel, paintPanel;

    private int holdNbr1, holdNbr2, holdNbr3;
    private Color initialColor = Color.RED;

    public MyColorChooser2() {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setTitle("Color Chooser");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        // Let DrawPanel choose the initial color. I don't care.
        drawPanel = new DrawPanel();
        // This way I control what is the initial color
        //drawPanel = new DrawPanel(initialColor);

        // set up labels
        redLabel = new JLabel("Red:");
        greenLabel = new JLabel("Green:");
        blueLabel = new JLabel("Blue:");

        // set up sliders and register their event handler:
        redSlider = new JSlider(SwingConstants.HORIZONTAL, 0, 255, initialColor.getRed());
        redSlider.setMajorTickSpacing(10); // create tick every 10
        redSlider.setPaintTicks(true); // paint ticks on slider

        greenSlider = new JSlider(SwingConstants.HORIZONTAL, 0, 255, initialColor.getGreen());
        greenSlider.setMajorTickSpacing(10); // create tick every 10
        greenSlider.setPaintTicks(true); // paint ticks on slider

        blueSlider = new JSlider(SwingConstants.HORIZONTAL, 0, 255, initialColor.getBlue());
        blueSlider.setMajorTickSpacing(10); // create tick every 10
        blueSlider.setPaintTicks(true); // paint ticks on slider

        // slider event handling:
        SliderHandler sliderHandler = new SliderHandler();
        redSlider.addChangeListener(sliderHandler);
        greenSlider.addChangeListener(sliderHandler);
        blueSlider.addChangeListener(sliderHandler);

        // set up textFields and register their event handler:
        redTextField = new JTextField(3);
        redTextField.setText("50"); // initialize
        redTextField.setEditable(false);
        redTextField.setText("" + redSlider.getValue());

        greenTextField = new JTextField(3);
        greenTextField.setText("100"); // initialize
        greenTextField.setEditable(false);
        greenTextField.setText("" + greenSlider.getValue());

        blueTextField = new JTextField(3);
        blueTextField.setText("200"); // initialize
        blueTextField.setEditable(false);
        blueTextField.setText("" + blueSlider.getValue());

        // build colorPanel:
        // build redPanel:
        redPanel = new JPanel();
        redPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
        redPanel.add(redLabel);
        redPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));
        redPanel.add(redSlider);
        redPanel.add(redTextField);
        // build greenPanel:
        greenPanel = new JPanel();
        greenPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
        greenPanel.add(greenLabel);
        greenPanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));
        greenPanel.add(greenSlider);
        greenPanel.add(greenTextField);
        // build bluePanel:
        bluePanel = new JPanel();
        bluePanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEFT));
        bluePanel.add(blueLabel);
        bluePanel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.CENTER));
        bluePanel.add(blueSlider);
        bluePanel.add(blueTextField);

        colorPanel = new JPanel();
        colorPanel.add(redPanel);
        colorPanel.add(greenPanel);
        colorPanel.add(bluePanel);

        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        frame.add(drawPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.add(colorPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);

        frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(900, 300));
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.pack();

    }

    private class DrawPanel extends JPanel {

        private Color color;
        private int red = 255, blue = 0, green = 0;

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            // I've removed the call to changeColor because it was creating
            // an infinite loop of revalidates and repaints.
            // Now, the paintComponent just finishes the job it was required to.
            super.paintComponent(g);
            g.setColor(color);
            g.fillRect(10, 10, 880, 200);
        }

        public DrawPanel() {
            this(Color.BLUE);
        }

        public DrawPanel(Color c) {
            color = c;
            red = color.getRed();
            green = color.getGreen();
            blue = color.getBlue();

            // I'm calling this first repaint here just to make
            // sure the panel is initiated the way we want with 
            // the given Color
            repaint();
        }

        void changeColor() {
            color = new Color(red, green, blue);
            // We just need to change the color and call this repaint here
            // so that the paintComponent can do its job
            repaint();
        }

        public void setRed(int r) {
            red = r;
            changeColor();
        }

        public void setBlue(int b) {
            blue = b;
            changeColor();
        }

        public void setGreen(int g) {
            green = g;
            changeColor();
        }
    }

    private class SliderHandler implements ChangeListener {

        @Override
        public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
            JSlider change = (JSlider) e.getSource();
            int value;

            // I've removed this line of code because you were
            // recreating the drawingPanel. That's not what you want.
            // You want to reuse the same panel.
            // DrawPanel draw = new DrawPanel();

            if (change == redSlider) {
                value = change.getValue();
                redTextField.setText(String.valueOf(value));
                drawPanel.setRed(value);
            } else if (change == greenSlider) {
                value = change.getValue();
                greenTextField.setText(String.valueOf(value));
                drawPanel.setGreen(value);
            } else if (change == blueSlider) {
                value = change.getValue();
                blueTextField.setText(String.valueOf(value));
                drawPanel.setBlue(value);
            }

            // You don't need to call those methods, because the
            // changeColor will be called by the settings 
            // of Red, Green            and Blue
            //       draw.changeColor();
            //       draw.repaint();

        }

    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        MyColorChooser2 color = new MyColorChooser2();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank You so much!!  One question is what is the purpose of     private Color initialColor = Color.RED; and then calling draw panel with the initialColor. Since there is no default method for the DrawPanel class does this have some significance?

Comment: I've done it that way so that you're able to choose the initialColor by changing the value of the field without having to look inside the class searching for it. The DrawPanel accepts an initial color so that it's able to initiate the red, green and blue sliders. But you could've done it differently, by removing the color from the DrawPanel constructor and by setting the default values of the sliders inside the DrawPanel class. You could combine both approaches with a default constructor that uses a specific color. I'll edit the answer, check it out.

Comment: Now you have a design problem. You initiate the drawPanel with a default color, but the sliders are instantiated with a different one. Did you see it? Try to redesign your code in order to make it work  properly both ways: by you choosing the initial color and by you letting the drawPanel choose the initial color for you.

Comment: I get what you are saying thanks for all your insight !!